# Java RMI: Register 2 different classes on server

Tags: java, rmi

Is there a way to register 2 different programs (different classes) to the same RMI registry on a machine (localhost)?  I currently have 2 netbeans projects that both try to rebind() to the same server with different names and objects but the second one always fails (I start the rmiregistry in the classes directory of the first project) with an "java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments" error (class not found understandbly). So is there a way to get more than one name<->class pair registered in the same RMI registry?

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You just have to arrange that the Registry has access to both sets of classes via its CLASSPATH, or use the codebase feature.